# MYSQL outputting nested data

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I am having trouble getting nested results in my output table.

```
SELECT *, users.Name FROM person WHERE person.User IN
( 
    SELECT Id FROM users WHERE users.Id = "0014082f-5e17-4eaa-aebc-a22800c59ccc"
)
```

In this example i want to select next to the data from person the Username of the nested table users. this piece of code gives the following error

```
 #1054 - Unknown column 'users.Name' in 'field list'
```

but what can i do to fix it?

EDIT:

i tried to simplify things but it only made my question more vague
This is the original code with the JOIN tip from the awnsers

```
SELECT * FROM behandelaars LEFT JOIN
( 
    SELECT Id, Name FROM users WHERE users.Id 
    IN(
        SELECT User FROM usersinrole WHERE Role IN (
            SELECT Id FROM roles WHERE Name = "BeloningHintingSysteem"
        )
    )
    AND users.Id NOT IN(
        SELECT User FROM usersinrole WHERE Role IN (
            SELECT Id FROM roles WHERE Name = "UitgelslotenVanOnderzoek"
        )
    )
)
ON behandelaars.User = users.Id
```

thx
Matthy

Comment: Try using join queries in stead of filtering with `IN(/* subquery */)`. It takes a bit of adjustment in the way you think but in the long run it's very useful.

Comment: It simply means that `Name` column doesn't exist in `users` table

Comment: @ParagTyagi more likely it means that the `users` table name is not visible in the main query.

Comment: thanks all for the comments the main problem why i am using the IN parameter now is because i think the nesting is going to get deeper. i migth have over simplified the example. i will try to improve the example

Comment: @Matthy: If you want fields from both the table, use JOIN. Check my answer if it works

Comment: @ParagTyagi i tried it but it give an error  #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias i am probarly doing something very wrong i added the code in my original post

Answer (score 1):

Try `JOIN` -

```
SELECT person.*, users.Name FROM person 
INNER JOIN users ON person.User = users.Id
WHERE users.Id = "0014082f-5e17-4eaa-aebc-a22800c59ccc"
```

Comment: i tried it but it give an error #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias i am probarly doing something very wrong i added the code in my original post

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure sub-queries with `IN / ANY / SOME` don't allow using the sub-queries tables outside of the sub-query.

In your particular case the sub-query is very simple and can easily be joined directly to the main query:

```
SELECT person.*, users.Name
    FROM person 
    LEFT JOIN users
      ON person.User = users.Id
    WHERE users.Id = "0014082f-5e17-4eaa-aebc-a22800c59ccc"
```

If the sub-query gets more complicated or requires grouping / aggregates that the main query doesn't require you can join a subquery:

```
SELECT person.*, a_new_alias_for_users.Name
    FROM person 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT Name
            FROM users
            WHERE users.Id = "0014082f-5e17-4eaa-aebc-a22800c59ccc"

    ) AS a_new_alias_for_users
    WHERE person.some_column <> 2;
```

Comment: thank you for the comments the main problem why i am using the IN parameter now is because i think the nesting is going to get deeper. i migth have over simplified the example

Comment: Joins are better at this than sub-queries. All SQL engies have been optimizing joins for the past few decades -- sub-query optimizations came later.

Comment: You are thinking in a very procedural way, try learning more about how joins work and it will change how you approach the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your last query returns ID, and you are comparing Role with ID.